# how do you deal with timezone issues?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, postgresql, timezone

For a scheduling system, what's the best way to save the timezone of client/event in a central server database coming from multiple sources mobile,web,client app.

- How do you store the dates? Alarms, reminders etc...
- How do you handle the DST setting?
- How do you handle the events if client has traveled to a different location?

I need the solution to work with all databases in tags.

Comment: Note that the answers listed below all suggest a pure-UTC approach, which is *not* ideal for the case of scheduling systems.  See accepted answer in dup post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the key points to the strategy I tend to use.

- Every date is UTC internally to the system.
- Users are shown dates in the their local timezone.
- We allow users to override the timezone they are using in case they travel and they want to keep the timezone consistent.
- Make the timezone easily visible. Either display it with the time or as part of the column header.

Answer (score 9):

Everything in UTC, and another column for the offset.

Comment: the offset can change when DST changes, how do you when you have to change the Offset?

Comment: Absolutely the right answer. If you don't use one specific timezone to base all your timestamps, etc, on, you're going to have a world of problems. Just use an offset lookup table with date ranges, and then link your user to that. Don't store the offset as an actual number.

Comment: The offset is stored as e.g. `EST5EDT`.

Comment: but that can change with DST, for example I am on `GMT+2` in winter and `GMT+3` in the summer

Comment: That makes you `EET2EEDT`. Or whatever the designation is.

Comment: I usually use zone names from ZoneInfo (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo) that are available in most of the system I use (java/postgresql/unix) and that do not change when DST occur

Comment: Check CONVERT_TZ in mysql. Check Steve g answer

Comment: PostgreSQL can convert timezone on-the-fly:  "SELECT timestamp_utc_field AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'", for example, converts the data in the field to the appropriate value, including adjustments for DST.

Answer (score 3):

Store dates as UTC timestamps - convert to local time when displaying data to the user.

Answer (score 0):

1. Safe to store in one specific time zone ideally in UTC
2. If you store the time with a date, you are safe in DST.
3. Suggesting you to use a web service to find the time difference.